# Images are upload in folder via form but name in DB is not image name. Instead it's a path to XAMPP tmp file?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

In my admin table, the column image is showing this path after the image uploads: C:\xampp\tmp\phpC6DA.tmp but image name don't. Image is perfectly uploaded to desired folder and that is ok...

I've tried to change varchar to text, for image column in MySQL. Maybe it's a XAMPP setting I don't know? MySQL is set as InnoDB.

This is a part of the code

```
$img              = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$img_tmp          = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($img_tmp, "upload/$img");

$db->query("INSERT INTO admin (id, full_name, email, password, gender, image) VALUES (NULL, :full_name, :email, :password, :gender, :image)");

$db->bindvalue(":full_name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->bindvalue(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->bindvalue(":password", $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->bindvalue(":gender", $gender, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$db->bindvalue(":image", $img_tmp, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$db->execute();
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$db->bindvalue(":image", $img_tmp, PDO::PARAM_STR);` be `$db->bindvalue(":image","upload/$img", PDO::PARAM_STR);` ?

Comment: why are you storing the temporary upload location? That doesn't exist after the session expires.. store `$img` and call `upload/$img` where applicable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$db->bindvalue(":image", $img_tmp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

With

```
$db->bindvalue(":image", $img, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

`$img` contains the name you want.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't saw that last night, probably because of too much looking :)